# HTML navigation bar inline items on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is my navigation bar (uses Bootstrap 4):

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light rounded-bottom" style="height: 60px;">
  <a class="navbar-brand text-blue font-weight-bold nav-link">Car Shop</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a href="cars.html" class="nav-link text-light" style="" id="nav_cars">Cars</a>
      <a href="engine.html" class="nav-link text-light" style="" id="nav_engine">Engine</a>
      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="create" style="background-color: #ffec00!important; position: absolute; margin-right: 0px; right: 15px; top: 11px;">Log Out</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So except the main title Cars Shop, there are three more items:

- Cars (aligned from the left)
- Engine (aligned from the left)
- Log Out button (in the top right corner)

On desktop it looks good, but when I switch to mobile (or resize window appropriately), the three items disappear completely. Is there any way to make this navbar a bit more user friendly?

Comment: You have used class `collapse` that is why it is hiding on small screens

Answer (score 0):

As far ad I understand the problem is that you are using a collapsed navbar without the ability to open it after it collapses. I fixed it like this for a collapsed menu (you will need to change up your style a bit to make it look good):

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light rounded-bottom" style="height: 60px;">
          <a class="navbar-brand text-blue font-weight-bold nav-link">Car Shop</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
          </button>
        
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <a href="cars.html" class="nav-link text-dark" style="" id="nav_cars">Cars</a>
              <a href="engine.html" class="nav-link text-dark" style="" id="nav_engine">Engine</a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn" name="create" style="background-color: #ffec00!important; position: absolute; margin-right: 3em; right: 15px; top: 11px;">Log Out</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

I would also recommend doing the CSS in a separate file if you aren't already and maybe try to use em, vh, vw instead of px.

Comment: For me, they disappear completely. No matter of which color they have. I even tried it before to hold pressed cursor and try to find them that way, but it wasn't anywhere.

Comment: I jumped to a conclusion earlier. Here is another go at it.

Comment: @Nik please use a [repro]  instead of fiddles. Questions and answers must be self-containing. If the link to the fiddle changes or is removed, the question would lose greatly on value. A working snippet `<>` can be added directly incl. the Bootstrap library.

Comment: @tacoshy Hopefully I did it the right way now.